# Do we need feed in chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat, rss

Do we need feed in chatroom for main site and meta site?

If yes then what should be the feed's bot name?

Comment: I think something like Radio Frequency or something to do with that!

Comment: @ihavenodirection I liked you opinion and set it the name as Radio Frequency until someone comes with better idea.

Comment: Some other suggestions are Bandwidth and AM/FM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**We don't need a feed for the main site**. People always check the main site for questions they can answer, especially for betas like ours. There's no real point to posting every new question into the chat itself because of this. Including posts from the main in the **news ticker** (the little drop down that goes in the top left) would be alright. If this site ever gets anywhere near the size of StackOverflow, we'll likely need to disable this, but that's a *long* time from now if at all.

**We should have a feed for the meta site**. Meta gets a lot less traffic but is pretty important to the site's definition and whether or not we finalize our scope. The more feedback and input from the community on these issues, the better. There aren't too many posts here on meta, especially since the initial wave is over, so it won't flood the chat.

Somewhat off topic, but let's [get in the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21415/music-fans) more! If no one is in there this question has no meaning.

Comment: Agreed many users rock at the main site, but devote less time to Meta and Chat.

Comment: Done...........